# Angular filter based on input and <ul> elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, filter

Have a custom dropdown select, make it with "input" and "ul li" elements.

When pressing on the li element, value of li set into input, but filtering not happens. When I write into "input" manual everything works fine

How to set data to input?

HTML

```
<div class="drop-down-input select-style-input selected">
                       <input ng-model="keyword.classname" id="simple_2" class="drop-down-select" placeholder="input text" type="text">
                       <ul  class="dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
                           <li ng-repeat="feedback in feedbacks">{{feedback.classname}}</li>

                       </ul>
                   </div>

<div class="feedback-container">
    <div ng-repeat="feedback in feedbacks | filter:keyword" class="feedback-row gt-clear group group-content">
        <div class="gt-left">
            <div class="ava-round-small"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gt-left right-side-fcontent">
            <div class="students-name"> {{feedback.username}}</div>
            <div class="text-feedback">{{feedback.feedback}}</div>
            <div class="feedback-img">
                <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

my JS

```
$(function() {
                $('.drop-down-input').click(function() {
                $('.drop-down-input.selected').removeClass('selected'); // Forget the previous selection
                 $(this).addClass('selected');
                $(this).find(".dropdown-list").show();
                });

                $(document).on("click", ".drop-down-input.selected li",
                        function(e) {
                         e.stopPropagation();
                         $('.drop-down-input.selected .dropdown-list').hide().siblings().val($(this).html());
                        });
                });
                $(document).mouseup(function (e){
                 var container = $(".dropdown-list");

                if (!container.is(e.target)
                   && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                  container.hide();
                }
                });
```

Comment: try  ng-repeat="feedback in feedbacks | filter:keyword.classname"

Comment: not working (((

Comment: This is not angular code. You use angular in your html, but not in your js.